# maven :: install multiple third-party artifacts to local repository at once from filesystem

Tags: maven, plugins, installation

We're using non-public artifacts from third-party companies in our project. We don't have maven proxy installed (and there're no plants to do so, because we found it complicates things rather than solves problems. especially if no internet connection or VPN is available).

So I created set of 'maven install file' plugin executions, like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-artifacts.1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFile>thirdparty/gwt-0.99.1.pom</pomFile>
                        <file>thirdparty/gwt-0.99.1.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-artifacts.2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFile>thirdparty/morphia-0.99.1.pom</pomFile>
                        <file>thirdparty/morphia-0.99.1.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-artifacts.3</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <pomFile>thirdparty/gwt-oauth2-0.2-alpha.pom</pomFile>
                        <file>thirdparty/gwt-oauth2-0.2-alpha.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

it works great and does exactly what we need. However if new artifact is added - new big XML section has to be added.

Is there any way to avoid this, like use 'yet another plugin' which will search for folder and install everything from it?

Comment: Whatever you end up doing will look suspiciously like a Maven proxy, so I suggest you revisit your previous attempts to use one. How does a developer get the files to install in the first place without a network connection?

Comment: I recommend you to go to a maven training and learn why a repository manager (proxy) will help you. You didn't understand the concept of Maven nor the concept of a repository manager sorry to say that clear.

Comment: @artbristol it gets artifacts from public repositiries.

Comment: @khmarbaise please try to read original post one more time. We tried maven proxy and realized that it introduces more problems than solves our needs.

Comment: What kind of problems did you have using a repository manager ? I would install those artifact exactly once in the repo-mgmt and afterwards i can use them as usual dependencies. That's it. So where is the problem? (apart from that i've read the post and had many customers with the same problem in misunderstandig of the maven concepts).

Comment: @khmarbaise the problem is that VPN always has to be enabled in order to access private repository. This really differs from vanilla scenarios, doesn't it? So if there're some issues with getting VPN connection - then it simply doesn't work. Considering the fact that recent version of Maven contains bug with repository caching - this complicates things ever more - see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5185

Comment: First the mentioned bug has some other relationships but that's a different story. The local repository is on your local harddrive  ($HOME/.m2/repository) and has nothing to do with VPN. The point is to solve dependencies which are not in the local repository which needs to be gotten from somewhere and now the RepoMgmr came into play. This access can be configured in $HOME/.m2/settings.xml which can handled by a VCS (like git) and can be switched to a different setting for working via VPN or without or with a different RepoMgmr which is simple and will solve the problems.

Comment: If your internet connection fails the RepoMgmr will take care of it. It seemed to me that you didn't understand the difference between local repository ($HOME/.m2/repository) and the RepoMgr (or may be Maven Central as an example). You can also work offline with maven (mvn -o)...it's only a problem if you need new dependenciey which never have been used before...

Comment: @khmarbaise you don't get me. I want to store some of dependencies in VCS. I don't care if somebody is maven zealot and pushes maven proxies so hard. I simply wanted to solve my problem and not looking for comments stating that I don't understand something. If you know how to install several files from a folder - please advice. Otherwise please stop flaming and demagogy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First storing dependencies in VCS is the wrong way. That's why you have Maven and it's dependency management and repoMgmr etc. To solve that you can simply go via a script which calls mvn install:install-file -DartifactId=.. etc. If you really want to go the wrong way ok it's your turn.

Comment: I gave this a plus 1 'cause I am developing an sdk that has to install all the .jar's we distribute.. and we can't assume that our users are running nexus.  Now of course they should be ;^)   But we have no control over that.  So this is a pretty good solution.. and i will borrow it... Thanks for posting !

Comment: @ChrisBedford I've got another solution with "local repositories", see http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/ - it works just GREAT with way less code.

Answer (score 3):

Best solution for such kind of thing is to install a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html). 
You've written you won't installing a proxy but that's the wrong way. The only solution to solve such kind of problems is to install a repository manager.